# Android: Issues with button opacity after TouchWiz UI update to Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: android, tablet, galaxy

It seems they recently updated the galaxy tab 10.1 to have the TouchWiz UI. Unfortunately, on this device, my buttons are now all showing with an alpha layer.  I've even tried doing this in the code, to keep it from happening, but I can't seem to get past the issue.  It wouldn't be so bad, but the button normally only shows an alpha layer when disabled.  this is a bit confusing.

Has anyone seen this or determined how to get past it?

here is the code I tried:

```
btnCustomer.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
```